# Displaying data from multiple classes in tableview

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

I am trying to populate a tableview with data from multiple classes. The below code is populating the table with data but it is creating a new row for every column.

Here is the code:

```
   try {
        col_Result_marks.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("MARKS"));
        col_Result_course.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("NAME"));
        col_Result_tstdt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("TSTDT"));
        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
        db.DBConn("SELECT blah blah...");
        ObservableList dataset = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while(db.resultSet.next()){
            Result rslt = new Result();
            rslt.setMARKS(db.resultSet.getInt("MARKS"));
            Test tst = new Test();
            tst.setTSTDT(db.resultSet.getDate("TST_DT"));
            Course crs = new Course();
            crs.setNAME(db.resultSet.getString("SUB"));
            dataset.addAll(rslt,tst,crs);
        }
        db.ConnClose();
        tbl_Result.setItems(dataset);

    }
```

and the output looks like something similar:

```
<null> <null> rslt
<null> tst <null> 
crs <null> <null>
```

I want the output to be:

```
rslt tst crs
```

Comment: You are adding three objects per SQL result to the data set, so JavaFX is adding three lines. What you probably will want to do is add a single class with a MARKS, rsr and src property.

Comment: @sarcan Creating a separate class for query output is not feasible if that is what you mean. I have separate class for each of my major entities. Any suggestions on implementing this? I am new to javafx so pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting three objects you can create a table view just with strings. Like this:

```
TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<>();
```

And define the columns to get Strings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLUMNS; i++) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col  = new TableColumn<>("Col#"+i);
        final int finalI = i;
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {          
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> cdf) {     
                return new SimpleStringProperty(cdf.getValue().get(finalI));
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(col);
    }
```

So, when you are updating the table view, you can build a list of string based on the three objects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does not work for me sadly. It says: The type Callback is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>,String>, ObservableValue<String>>